# Is there value in passing a global variable to a function?

Tags: javascript

I recently saw code that looks like this:

```
(function (someGlobal) {
    someGlobal.DoSomething();
})(someGlobal);
```

where someGlobal was a large framework class.  It could be JQuery.  What is the benefit of doing this?  Is it a good practice?  It seems like this code would be equivalent and less error prone because you don't hide the global:

```
(function () {
    someGlobal.DoSomething();
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have a reliable reference in case the global one gets overwritten
- It shortens the scope chain to access it

---

> *"It seems like this code would be equivalent and less error prone because you don't hide the global:*"
>
> ```
> (function () {
>     someGlobal.DoSomething();
> })();
> ```

If you anticipate the global being overwritten, and your code *relies on* the overwritten value, then clearly you wouldn't want to shadow it by a local variable in a function.

Aside from that, the local reference in a function shouldn't be any more prone to error.

Comment: 1. Only if you are **certain** the code will execute before the global is overwritten. 2. Only by one scope object, so an increadibly small gain (since compilers likely optimise scope chains on function instantiation). So the benefits are pretty small.

Comment: @RobG: 1. Well if it doesn't execute first, then there's a problem to solve. We could just as well say *"Only if you are certain the global existed in the first place"*, but that would be beside the point, wouldn't it? If the global is overwritten, then the IIFE question is moot. 2. Yes, a small performance gain.

Comment: Code that is intended to run in an environment where globals it depends on may be reassigned is likely also in an environment where it doesn't know whether it will run before or after code that might do that reassignment. In such cases, passing in a global doesn't provide any certainty that it hasn't already been reassigned. After all, isn't that the point of globals?

Answer (score 1):

I agree if it's a global variable then why pass it? Just use it as a global.

However it does seem like this could be a valid transition mechanism to remove a global.  For instance if I inheritted a large code base with a lot of globals, one potential transition mechanism would be to slowly eliminate the global usages in this exact manner.  The change could be done this way incrementally with minimal diffs.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit is that, within that function, `someGlobal` is unambiguous.

Comment: How is it more unambiguous than the reference to it being passed in as a parameter?  If you don't know what the global is in the function, you won't know what it is at the calling site.

Comment: @SteveRowe, this pattern is more useful in broader scenarios where the calling sites are "distant" from the declaration of the function and there are closures involved. As others have better said, `someGlobal` might change in the middle of the way between the inception of the function and its usage. From the point of view of the code within the function, the parameter value (or, the reference to the argument that was passed) won't change.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can use an alias name in a safe scope.

```
(function ($) {
    $.DoSomething();
})(someGlobal);
```

***Update:***

The most import thing is this way defined a safe scope for you to use `someGlobal`.

If you use the second way, the `someGlobal` is still an global, just imaging that you use `someGlobal` in an callback function,  and you overwrite `someGlobal` somewhere outside, what will happen?

Comment: That would be a benefit, but in this case, they used the exact same name.

Comment: @SteveRowe Yes, besides that, the more import thing is that define a safe scope for you to use `someGlobal`.

Comment: Trying to understand here.  If the function is only called once (notice the reference isn't captured anywhere and it is anonymous), does that safe scope help?  Even if it were called multiple times, is there true danger that something like JQuery/$ will be over-written?

Comment: @SteveRowe Yes, the `someGlobal` is what the `someGlobal` you passed it.

Comment: But why would someGlobal resolve differently at calling time than at execution time?  The two should be nearly simultaneous.